# Creating two maps with the same color ramp

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a map of a country divided into regions. I then color each region based on an attribute that tells me the average income of the region in 1990 (symbology - categorized - color ramp - blues). Then I make a copy of the map and I color the regions according to their average income in 2020 using the same procedure. How can I make sure that the scale used to determine the color of each region in one map matches exactly the scale of the other map, so that the maps are comparable?

Comment: What do you mean by scale of the blues?

Comment: for example, an income of 20,000 should have exactly the same color in both maps

Comment: Please [edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on the layer, there will be a Copy Style option (slightly different depending on whether your layer is vector or raster).

You can then Paste Style on to the layer for your 2020 map. The scales will be retained.